# How to Scrape a popup page using python and selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape off info from a pop up page. It has names of the NGOs in a table format and on clicking on each name gives way to a pop up page. In my code below, I'm extracting the onclick attribute for each NGO and storing it in a variable. I want to use this variable to make a post request to get the pop up page. (I've also tried accessing it using selenium. It didn't work.

How should I get my code to open these pop up links for scraping data off them?

HTML behind the page

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="show_ngo_info(161456);">Name</a>
```

Code portion is below

```
 html = requests.get("http://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/31/35/1")
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
 first_div = soup.find ('div',  class_ = "ibox-content")
 get_tr = first_div.find_all('a', onclick=True)
 for ngoinfo in get_tr:
 try:
    if re.match('show_ngo_info',ngoinfo['onclick']):    
        k = ngoinfo['onclick']
        p = re.sub("\D", "", k)
except:pass
```

Comment: Is it the number `161456` you wanna parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have dynamic information loaded on the web page, you should inspect what calls the page do to get this dynamic information. You can use the Inspection Tools from your web browser to find that.

Inspecting the page I saw that when you click on one of the links to show the popup, the page does two requests, the first got a **CSRF token** and the second got information that will have displayed in the popup.

I think you should try to simulate these calls with Python. I couldn't test this, but I think this is the approach.

- First: **GET** http://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf
- Second: **POST** http://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info

  - You should send the id that you got before

I discovered this when I inspected the network in browser inspection tools.

You will need to do these calls for each link you are extracting.

I hope that can help you.

Comment: hey @klassmann, I have updated my code, but it generates a 403 error. Not sure, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403, Are you sending the token and the ID in the POST request? I think you only need the token and ID together. Maybe the website needs another way to authenticate the request; you should inspect what the page does with when it loads the dynamic data.

Comment: I have an identical problem I am trying to solve.  Where did you find the two requests this page makes?

Comment: Open the DevTools of your Browser, and keep watching the Network tab, mark only XHR(Ajax Requests). Open this web site https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/31/35/1 and after load you can click in any name(Name of VO/NGO) in the table, when click it will open a popup and the page will do these two ajax requests. I used Chrome: https://imgur.com/a/ohjvUXl 
If you want a more complete answer add a new question, here is not the best place for doing this!